# CSS rule to auto-resize textarea upon text

Tags: html, css, textarea

Let's suppose I have a `textarea`. I would like to resize the height of the `textarea` automatically each time its value/text is changed. It can be done with Javascript, but I am interested to know whether there is a pure HTML/CSS solution.

Comment: Can you tell me why? I guess this could be transformed into an accepted answer.

Comment: The reason being, interaction can be captured only by JavaScript.

Comment: The referred question was about purely doing it with CSS. My question was about HTML and CSS, not only CSS.

Comment: CSS is nothing without HTML, FYI. `:)`

Comment: So you think they are the same? Good to know.

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done using pure CSS at least for `<textarea>`, the reason being, interaction can be captured only by JavaScript. But you can make something like `<div>` having a `contenteditable`, a *fake* `<textarea>` can be made possible.

**Snippet**

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div contentEditable></div>
```